# Problems using Ngrok for testing. Am using IIS & Flask under Windows

Tags: windows, flask, iis, ngrok

Developing a web application using IIS and Flask under Windows. IIS listens on port 80 and Flask on 5000. Am trying to use ngrok for testing. I am setting the ngrok to tunnel to the iis (ngrok http 80) which displays the login page. To authenticate the user the login page needs to connect to Flask /login route. What connection string should I use?

1. Tried to use the URL provided by ngrok (UrlProvideByNgrok/FlaksRout} which, obviously, didn't work.

2, Tried to tunnel to the flask's / route (ngrok http 5000) and redirect to the login page, however still had the problem of connecting to different routes in the Flask app.

3. Tried: fetch("/api/data") // Relative URL to Flask rout which did not work either.

Comment: I don't know about ngrok, but I know that if you want to create a connection between IIS (port 80) and Flask (port 5000), you need to configure IIS to act as a reverse proxy to forward requests to Flask. This is done by enabling the ARR proxy service and adding URL rewrite rules. You need to install the URL Rewrite module and Application Request Routing Cache module before setting it up.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced IIS with Nginx as a web and a reverse server and, as you suggested, made the connection between 80 to the 5000 ports. Now, the whole thing, including Ngrok is working.

Comment: That’s great. Glad you got it working! You can post an answer describing the solution and accept it.  This will lead more people in the right direction.